# Parallel programming in R

Tags: json, r, twitter

I have a file that consists of multiple JSON objects. I need to read through these files and extract certain fields from the JSON objects. To complicate things, some of the objects do not contain all the fields. I am dealing with a large file of over 200,000 JSON objects. I would like to split job across multiple cores. I have tried to experiment with doSNOW, foreach, and parallel and really do not understand how to do this. The following is my code that I would like to make more efficient.

```
foreach (i in 2:length(linn)) %dopar% {
  json_data <- fromJSON(linn[i])


  if(names(json_data)[1]=="info")
    next

  mLocation <- ifelse('location' %!in% names(json_data$actor),'NULL',json_data$actor$location$displayName)
  mRetweetCount <- ifelse('retweetCount' %!in% names(json_data),0,json_data$retweetCount)
  mGeo <- ifelse('geo' %!in% names(json_data),c(-0,-0),json_data$geo$coordinates)

  tweet <- rbind(tweet, 
               data.frame(
                 record.no        =     i,
                 id               =     json_data$id,
                 objecttype       =     json_data$actor$objectType,
                 postedtime       =     json_data$actor$postedTime,
                 location         =     mLocation,
                 displayname      =     json_data$generator$displayName,
                 link             =     json_data$generator$link,
                 body             =     json_data$body,
                 retweetcount     =     mRetweetCount,
                 geo              =     mGeo)
               )

}
```

Comment: It's time you learned to post code chunks in SO correctly. (Also  `%!in%` is not a standard operator  ... you should include the names of all packages being depended upon to make this code run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to parallelize an iteration, I think you're better off trying to vectorize (hmm, actually most of the below is still iterating...). For instance here we get all our records (no speed gain yet, though see below...)

```
json_data <- lapply(linn, fromJSON)
```

For `location` we pre-allocate a vector of NAs to represent records for which there is no location, then find records that *do* have a location (maybe there's a better way of doing this...) and update them

```
mLocation <- rep(NA, length(json_data))
idx <- sapply(json_data, function(x) "location" %in% names(x$actor))
mLocation[idx] <- sapply(json_data[idx], function(x) x$location$displayName)
```

Finally, create a 200,000 row data frame in a single call (rather than your 'copy and append' pattern, which makes a copy of the first row, then the first and second row, then the first, second, third row, then ... so N-squared rows, in addition to recreating factors and other data.frame specific expenses; this is likely where you spend most of your time)

```
data.frame(i=seq_along(json_data), location=mLocation)
```

The idea would be to accumulate all the columns, and then do just one call to `data.frame()`. I think you could cheat on parsing line-at-a-time, by pasting everything into a single string repersenting a JSON array, and parsing in one call

```
json_data <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(linn, collapse=",")))
```

Comment: Your post got me thinking about this. I created a matrix of columns and rows of NA and then inserted the values where I needed them and then converted to a data frame. So much better. Thank you.